# Is Codeigniter suport route naming if support what is the syntaxt or give me some link

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Laravel has an option of **named routing** like this

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');
```

Is it possible to achive same thing using named routing in **Codeigniter**?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well the best way to check that out is to go and read about it from the user guide.

The link is [CodeIgniter User Guide - Routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=routing)

Comment: Well then you know the answer... Not in it's latest incarnation.